Change render visibility of collection at start/end of action
I have two collections of objects, one is for a walk cycle and the other is for an idle cycle of two things that look visually similar but are not the same. The end goal is to have two things which look like 2d sprites but are animated in 3d space which is why they are not the same objects in both collections (I could potentially morph the meshes from one collection into the shapes of the other but this seems needlessly time consuming). I want to have one action which plays the armature's animation and at the start of the animation, hides the other collection in render. And another action tied to a different armature which, when played, hides the collection associated with the other animation. The end goal is to import this into Godot so that each action can be triggered by in game events, and I don't think Godot likes Blender's modifiers. It appears I can create a new driver from a collections visibility but it just copies the information to a clip board and I do not know how to use it. Please let me know how I can use an action start as a driver for a collections render visibility, or if I am going about this in completely the wrong way, let me know how to switch between collections during actions.

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your setup, but wouldn't it be easier to export the 2 different "cycles" separately and let Godot's State Machine handle the transitions?

I agree with @ChristopherBennett here but I have to admit I'm not familiar with Godot. As you said, Godot probably doesn't "like" Blender's modifiers, but animating the collection visibility? I don't know if Godot "likes" Blender's concept of collections and I highly doubt it "likes" Blender's visibility settings.

That is probably the way to go, yeah. Thank you both I'll do that instead.
